# Create Java Array from one element of JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, url

I have a JSON Array at this url:
    https://gcc.azure-api.net/traffic/v1/movement/now

And it takes the form of:

```
[
    {
        "type": "irrelevant",
        "lastUpdate": "irrelevant",
        "batchIdentifier": "irrelevant",
        "site": "Irrelevant",
        "timestamp": "irrelevant",
        "flow": 18,
        "concentration": "irrelevant",
        "id": "irrelevant",
        "_id": "irrelevant"
    },
    {
        "type": "irrelevant",
        "lastUpdate": "irrelevant",
        "batchIdentifier": "irrelevant",
        "site": "Irrelevant"
        "timestamp": "irrelevant",
        "flow": 26,
        "concentration": "irrelevant",
        "id": "irrelevant",
        "_id": "irrelevant"
    }
]
```

I need to be able to get these values for variable "flow" for each element of this array, and place it into a java array of integers. I need this to continually download the JSON to work in real time so thus it must be parsed from the URL but I am really struggling to find any working method to doing this without simply crashing my app.

Below is a method I have thrown together that just does not work it is simply a combination of different solutions that are now working for me, any explanation would be helpful thank you.

```
public static void main() {

    float[] flowArray = null;

    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(getText("https://gcc.azure-api.net / traffic / v1 / movement / now"));
        int len = json.length();

        //iterate loop
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
            String flow = jsonObject.getString("flow");

            float flowNum = Float.parseFloat(flow);
            flowArray[i] = flowNum;
        }

    } catch (Exception Ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unexpected exception");
    }
}

public String getText(String url) throws Exception {
    URL website = new URL("https://gcc.azure-api.net/traffic/v1/movement/now");
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        response.append(inputLine);

    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: What will you do with this integers array/list?

Comment: @LppEdd I will be using it in a simple if statement to determine if the value of one of the "flow" elements is above X to determine if the junction is busy

Comment: "Continually" is a broad term, I'd say you need to continually *poll* the remote resource, you can do that using a ScheduledExecutoreService. But that depends on how often you need refreshed data

Comment: @LppEdd I can just call upon the class to be run in the app every so often, simply all I need right now is to create an array containing every "flow" value from within the JSON URL directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library. Example usage:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonPathApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://gcc.azure-api.net/traffic/v1/movement/now");

        List<Integer> flows = JsonPath.parse(url).read("$[*].flow");
        System.out.println(flows);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[13,35,0,18,4,9,11,0,18,18,0,0,0,13,14,0,5,4,4,9,22,18,22,4,0,22,0,45,13,9,31,28,4,2,9,0,0,0,9,9,13,10,14,9,0,13,18,31,33,0]
```

But if you really need to use `JSONArray` you can do it like below:

```
List<Integer> flows = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray objects = JSONArray.fromObject(json);
objects.iterator().forEachRemaining(o -> flows.add(((JSONObject) o).getInt("flow")));
System.out.println(flows)
```

Where `json` parameter is `String`. `JSON*` classes come from `net.sf.json.*` package.

Comment: Thanks for this! Not able to get the import statement to register correctly in android studio, do you have the dependencies?

Comment: @IanMann, Take a look on this [URL](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.4.0) and link to [net.sf.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4)

Answer (score 0):

See the working example below. Some comments:

1. The value of `flow` in JSON is not in parenthesis. → It is not a string but a number. Use `.getInt(...)` instead of `.getString(...)`.
2. Initialize array instead of null: `float[] flowArray = null;` → `int[] flowArray = new int[len];`.
3. The method `main(...)` should be static if you use it as an entry point for the application.

```java
    public static String getText(String url) throws Exception {
        URL website = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new 
                InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF8"));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            response.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
        return response.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(getText(
                    "https://gcc.azure-api.net/traffic/v1/movement/now"));
            int len = json.length();
            int[] flowArray = new int[len];
            //iterate loop
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
                flowArray[i] = jsonObject.getInt("flow"); 
            }
        } catch (Exception Ex) {
            Ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't work with primitive arrays in the first place. Use an higher level `Collection<T>` implementation such as a `List<T>`.

```
final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getText("..."));
final List<String> flows = new ArrayList(jsonArray.length());

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   final JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   final int flow = jsonObject.getInt("flow");
   flows.add(flow);
}

return flows;
```